# Problems at installing elementary OS in emmc

Tags: system-installation

I have a problem to install elementary OS. I do all of the proceedings and it shows me that I need to reset my laptop. I restart it but it still shows me that I need to install it again.

I have had this problem when Ubuntu but I found a solution in installing like a made factory, the problem is that in elementary OS it doesn't show me this operation.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like you're choosing the live image instead of installing it? What do you do after you've booted Elementary OS from something like a live usb / cd?

Maybe the following articles help. 
https://elementary.io/docs/installation
https://itsfoss.com/guide-install-elementary-os-luna/
http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2016/09/how-to-install-elementary-os-04-loki.html

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the live image is booting again. Have you removed the installation media (USB, DVD) etc after installation?